# Remove seconds in the date-time number in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column of date-time numbers, "DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS". At this moment, I want to remove "SS" from it and left "DD/MM/YY HH:MM". I tried DATE and TIME function separately but only one part left, `DATE`:"DD/MM/YY" and `TIME`:"HH:MM", also, I tried `CONCATENATE` function but it doesn't work, so could anyone do me a favour? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the values right-aligned or left aligned in the cell? If you narrow the column do they turn into ####### or spill over to the next column?

Comment: you need to store the modified second-less version, or just DISPLAY the time with no seconds?

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped. ##### appeared if I narrow the column.

Comment: @MarcB, do you mean that divide it into two parts? I think it is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the cell(s) to be modified and tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. Go to the *Number* tab and chose *Custom* from the list down the left. Supply the following for the *Type:*

```
dd/mm/yy hh:mm    ◄ EN-US
pp/kk/vv tt:mm    ◄ FI-FI
```

Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and you should be set.

[image: Ctrl+1 Custom Number Format]

Comment: Sorry it hint "Microsoft Excel cannot use the number format you typed."

Comment: Sorry, cannot tell what could possibly be wrong unless your Windows is running under some odd system regional settings.

Comment: I guess it is the problem with the type of the date stored in my system, it is a Finnish type, I may first try to switched the language in excel. Anyway, thinks.

Comment: I've access the FI-FI Custom Number format page [here](https://support.office.com/fi-fi/article/Oman-lukumuotoilun-luominen-tai-poistaminen-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4?ui=en-US&rs=fi-FI&ad=US&fromAR=1). Try `pp/kk/vv tt:mm` .

Answer (score 8):

If you want to completely remove the seconds from the data.
Try: `=1*TEXT(C2,"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")`

Multiplying the text result by 1 converts the text back to a number.

Comment: This is the proper answer. The OP asked how to convert, not how to format!

Comment: Was getting some superfluous seconds in user data entry, while only needing precision of minutes. This helped me sanitize the inputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `LEFT`.  Assuming I understand your question and you have `DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS` in one cell, you can use `=LEFT(cell,14)`

Comment: Are the data in the column hard-coded or are they created via referencing other cells?

Comment: I download somewhere. But I think I already know what is the problem now. The date is stored with a US type but my excel is in Finnish type.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
Round(CELL * 60 * 24 , 0)/60/24
```

Comment: As much as I like this answer, it's not guaranteed to always work since it rounds up. For instance I'm sure it'll fail for a time like 23:59:59. the [`ROUNDDOWN`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/rounddown-function-2ec94c73-241f-4b01-8c6f-17e6d7968f53) function might work better but I'm not too certain

Answer (score 0):

Try `=TEXT(A1,"DD/MM/YY HH:MM")`

Answer (score 0):

I have a column showing dates "27/01/2015  18:43:00"

I changed them to show as Number "42031.78"

I then used Data/Text to columns and used the period or full stop as the delimiter.

This gave me two columns "42031.00" and "7798611111.00"

I deleted the second column and changed the original column back to short date format. "27/01/2015"

No more hours and seconds!

Answer (score 0):

to remove the seconds just do =INT("cell number"*1440)/1440